# Why am I getting wrappedPointCut instead of the data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

I have 3 tiers of nested objects stored in mongoDB.
The first tier shows the name like it is supposed to, the second as well. 
But when it goes in to the third tier it shows the text:"wrappedPointCut"
Why is this? and What does wrapedPointCut mean??

I have a handlebars test code like this:

```
{{#each tierOne}}
<h2>{{ this.tierOneName }}</h2>
  {{#each tierTwo}}
    <h2>{{ this.tierTwoName }}</h2>        
    {{#each tierThree}}
    <h2>{{ this.tierThreeName }}</h2>
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
</div>
```

When iterating through the nested objects in JS I get the correct output in console. Also if I add 4 objects to the third tier I get 4 headers that read:"wrapedPointCut". This must mean it knows that there is data here.

this is the mongoDB structure:
this is the Tier 3:

```
var TierThree = new mongoose.Schema({
    tierThreeName : {
        type: String
    }
});
```

this is the Tier 2:

```
var TierTwo = new mongoose.Schema({
    tierTwoName : {
        type: String
    },
    tierThree : [TierThree]
});
```

this is the Tier 1:

```
var TierOne = mongoose.Schema({
    tierOneName : {
        type: String,
        index:true
    },
    tierTwo: [TierTwo]

});
```

Here is the function that exports the third tier to monngoDB:

```
module.exports.createTierThree = function(newTierThree, tierOne, tierTwoName , callback){
for (var i = 0; i < tierOne.tierTwo.length; i++) {
        if(tierOne.tierTwo[i].tierTwoName == tierTwoName ){                
            tierOne.tierTwo[i].tierThree.push(newTierThree);
            tierOne.tierTwo[i].save(function (err) {
                if (!err) console.log('Success!');
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: It would help if you show one example of your data exported in json format

Comment: I have made an edit and I hope this helps to clear it up. I would very much appreciate some help with this as I am so lost here. I think my problem might be in the way I iterate as shown in the first part....

Comment: This is not what I expected : could you provide a sample of data with whom you call your handlebar template.

Comment: I'm still not sure 100% sure what you needed. But there is a .js file in routes that call a function defined in models(shown in the bottom). This function takes the new tierThree obect, the tierOne parent object and the name of the tierTwo object as parameter. It then loops to the correct place and pushes the new third tier object. This seems to work fine since I now can create a JS code that iterates through and can write the new tier three object to console. But if I do the same using handlebars as shown on top I only get wrapedPointCut when printting the third tier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be that I'm doing something wrong when adding to database. If I add to the database using shell command everything is fine. So the problem now is to turn mongoDB shell command to JS.